# How to reduce the size of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am currently in the process of creating a gem and it seems to be considerably bigger than comparative gems.

First of all is this really an issue and if so is there a particular way to reduce the size of the gem?

Gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/roroacms

Github: https://github.com/roroacms/roroacms

Comment: did you compare with another rails cms (like refinery)?

Comment: I would say that size isn't an issue.  It's only loaded when your server starts up, it's not like you're serving it to anyone in a response or something.  However it's always worth understanding more about what you're doing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gem's `spec/` directory has, when unpacked, over 99MB. You should definitely exclude it from the final gem (even if small). The reason it's so large is because it contains the dummy app with `log/` (80MB) and `tmp/` (18MB) directories still present.

The way you exclude the files is though the `files` variable in the `gemspec`. The variable holds an array of every file that will be put into the built gem.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
    gem.files = `git ls-files`.split($/).reject { |fn| fn.start_with? "spec" }
    ...
end
```

The code will first get the list of every file in the directory (with `git ls-files` it will also apply the rules from `.gitignore`) and then removes any file whose path starts with `spec`.

It's up to you whether you want to include the tests in the final gem or not. The problem is that there's not a easy way of runing the tests. There used to be an option (`-t`) to do that directly via Rubygems but that option has been removed quite some time ago. Given the situation, I think it's probably for the best to just keep the tests in the repository.

Note that you might also see a variable called `test_files` in a `gemspec`. That variable is deprecated and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense. I thought it was good practice to keep tests within the gem? If this is not the case then I can remove them, what is the best way to ignore files from a gem?

Comment: @user2323463 I've expanded the answer.

Comment: I guess this is no longer needed as it looks like new engines contain a line to only include relevant files:

     Gem::Specification.new do |s|`
          s.files = Dir['{app,config,db,lib}/**/*', 'MIT-LICENSE', 'Rakefile', 'README.md']`