# rake release does not work

Tags: rubygems

I'm trying to release a new version of my gem running this command:

`rake release --trace`

but the process is stuck here:

```
rake release --trace
** Invoke load_app (first_time)
** Execute load_app
** Invoke release (first_time)
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Execute build
paperclip_upload 1.2.0 built to pkg/paperclip_upload-1.2.0.gem.
** Invoke release:guard_clean (first_time)
** Execute release:guard_clean
** Invoke release:source_control_push (first_time)
** Execute release:source_control_push
Tag v1.2.0 has already been created.
** Invoke release:rubygem_push (first_time)
** Execute release:rubygem_push
```

Things I tried and didn't work:

- Remove the github tag and release again.
- Update gem to last version (2.4.8) doing `gem update --system`.
- Reset my rubygems API key.
- Use the api. `curl --data-binary @pkg/paperclip_upload-1.2.0.gem -H 'Authorization:XXX' https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems`

  > The POST is not working but I can retrieve my gems performing a GET.
- Use [gems](https://github.com/rubygems/gems)

  ```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'gems'

  Gems.configure do |config|
    config.username = 'xxx'
    config.password = 'xxx'
  end

  Gems.push(File.new("pkg/paperclip_upload-1.2.0.gem"))
  ```
- Avoid to use the rake task executing `gem build` and then `gem push -v      pkg/paperclip_upload-1.2.0.gem` but is stuck too:

  ```
  gem push -v pkg/paperclip_upload-1.2.0.gem
  GET https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
  302 Moved Temporarily
  GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
  304 Not Modified
  GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
  302 Moved Temporarily
  GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
  200 OK
  GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rubygems-update-2.4.8.gemspec.rz
  302 Moved Temporarily
  GET http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/rubygems-update-2.4.8.gemspec.rz
  200 OK
  Pushing gem to http://rubygems.org/...
  POST http://rubygems.org//api/v1/gems
  connection reset after 1 requests, retrying
  POST http://rubygems.org//api/v1/gems
  connection reset after 1 requests, retrying
  ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
      too many connection resets (http://rubygems.org//api/v1/gems)
  ```

Any clue?

[RubyGems’ status page](https://status.rubygems.org/) is all green for me.

Comment: i did not know you can use names like `pkg/something` for gems. are you sure that this is supposed to work?

Comment: `pkg` is the directory, not a part of the gem's name. I tried to do it executing `gem push paperclip_upload-1.2.0.gem` inside pkg dir without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my problem [How to reduce the size of a gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544137/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-a-gem)

Trying to send a gem with 585MB of tmp junk is not the best idea...

Answer (score 1):

For me, after enabling [2FA on Rubygems.org](https://guides.rubygems.org/setting-up-multifactor-authentication/) I wasn't able to run `rake release` any more.

The `release:rubygem_push` step was hanging. Turns out [older versions of `gem` don't support 2FA](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6854), and intermediate versions had a bug where the process is [waiting for 2FA code entry but there's no prompt](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2774).

The solution for me was to type in a 2FA code + `return` when the process was waiting.

Eventually you should be able to `gem update --system` to get a new version of `gem` with full 2FA support.